# Get the all element of an array - php

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have an array:

```
array(1) {
  [14]=>
  array(1) {
    [976]=>
    array(1) {
      [79833]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(2) "99"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this is a html form:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="mark[14][976][79833][id]" >
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I need help to export all data from this input form;

for example:

```
$input="mark";
$first="14";
$second="976";
$Third="79833";
$Fourth="id";
$last_posted_typed_data="99"; (for example)
```

How can I do this? Thx!

Comment: Will all your form inputs have the same array structure?

Comment: For this case answer is Yes :) but I have some inputs in the same form, like this: <input type="text" name="lst[971][31876][lecture]" > and this: name='f[972][37480][comment][2][mark]'. thx

Comment: Can you change the inputs?  Would be easier and make more sence.

Comment: Can you give me any recommendations?

Comment: Use hidden inputs rather than a non-semantic multidimensional array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you mean by export, but the way you have it written now I think the way to get it is with a several-levels-nested loop.

```
foreach ($_POST as $input => $firsts) {
    foreach ($firsts as $first => $seconds) {
        foreach ($seconds as $second => $thirds) {
            foreach ($thirds as $third => $fourths) {
                foreach ($fourths as $fourth => $last_posted_typed_data) {
                    // do stuff with $input, $first, $second, $third, 
                    // $fourth, $last_posted_typed_data
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Kind of cumbersome, but without knowing more of what this is and what you're doing with it, I'm not sure how to suggest something better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure about specifics but You can use a recursive function to process input data, it will help when you don't know about the count of nested entities. All keys and values will save to the $results array.

```
<?php

function processData($data, &$results) {
    if (is_array($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $results[] = $key;
            processData($value, $results);
        }
    } else {
        $results['formValue'] = $data;
    }
}

$results = [];
processData($_POST, $results);
```

Answer (score 0):

With [***RecursiveIteratorIterator***](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) class:

```
$arr = [14 => [
    976 => [79833 => ['id' => 99]]
]];

$keys = [];
$data = "";
$it = new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr);   // iterator

foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $k => $v) {
    $keys[] = $k;
    if ($k == 'id') $data = $v;
}

list($first, $second, $third, $fourth) = $keys;
var_dump($first, $second, $third, $fourth, $data);
```

The output:

```
int(14)
int(976)
int(79833)
string(2) "id"
int(99)
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php

```
function array_values_recursive($array) {
  $flat = array();

  foreach($array as $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $flat = array_merge($flat, array_values_recursive($value));
    }
    else {
        $flat[] = $value;
    }
  }
  return $flat;
}
```